# How can I generate chained method expressions for LINQ and Entity Framework at runtime?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I am working a a small library that generates 'where' expressions at runtime. I've been able to navigate object properties and query using different operators like `Expression.Equal`, `Expression.NotEqual` and even the `.Contains()` method on strings.

I've run into a situation where I need to create an expression that represents chained methods, like this: `x => x.SomeColumn.Trim().EndsWith("SomeText")`. I'm not sure where to start with this.

I've implemented the `.EndsWith()` method already like this:

```
static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetEndsWithExpression(
    ParameterExpression parameterExpression,
    Expression propertyExpression,
    Expression valueToFind)
{
    var propertyExp = propertyExpression;
    var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var someValue = valueToFind;
    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExpression);
}
```

I'm wondering if you can help me figure out how to add the `.Trim()` method and chain it with the `.EndsWith()` method.

Some other info, I'm already using LINQKit in my project, so things like `.AsExpandable()` are somewhat familiar to me.

### My initial (wrong) approach (Updated)

I think that a solution would look something like this:

```
static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetTrimEndsWithExpression(
    ParameterExpression parameterExpression,
    Expression propertyExpression,
    Expression valueToFind)
{
    var propertyExp = propertyExpression;

    var trimMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim");
    var endsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });

    var trimMethodExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExp, trimMethod).Expand();
    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(trimMethodExpression, endsWithMethod, valueToFind);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExpression);
}
```

However, this fails to compile. It throws an error:

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
```

How do I go about chaining these two methods in an expression generated at runtime?

Comment: My initial approach is incorrect. I'm editing my question to show my actual approach and the actual error.

Comment: see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx) you need specify which `Trim` you want

Comment: I didn't know MSDN had a Russian language version :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is throwing the "Ambiguous match found" exception:

```
 var trimMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim");
```

Change it to:

```
var trimMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", new Type[0]);
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked in my initial test... Before I mark as the answer I'm gonna write a few more tests for sanity's sake just to make sure it's working the way I think it is.

Comment: @quakkels see more samples with `GetMethod`, possibly you want trim specific symbols

Answer (score 5):

The easy way to handle this is to write a `Compose` method that will allow you to compose one expression within another, which solves this problem in the general case:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> Compose<T, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<T, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermedaite, TResult>> second)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(
        second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], first.Body),
        first.Parameters[0]);
}
```

It uses the `Replace` method to replace all instances of one expression with another, which is defined below:

```
public class ReplaceVisitor:ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression ex)
    {
        if(ex == from) to;
        else return base.Visit(ex);
    }  
}

public static Expression Replace(this Expression ex,
    Expression from,
    Expression to)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(from, to).Visit(ex);
}
```

Now that we have that, we can compose the expressions that we want:

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> EndsWith<TEntity>(
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> propertySelector,
    string endsWith)
{
    return propertySelector.Compose(str => str.Trim().EndsWith(endsWith));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Very detailed and useful information.